# GET SUM of particular column along with value of another column in last row

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I am newbie to Sql, I want to get SUM of a particular column from a table and also the value of another Column from the table which is in the last row of column used in SUM.

For Eg:
Below is my Table I want sum of all amount fields where Code is 1 and and also a qty field which is at the last occurrence of code with value 1 in table

Table Image

[image]

I want some thing like below

```
select SUM(amount) from table where Code = 1 UNION ALL Select qty from test where Code = 1 and id = MAX(id) for/where code = 1 ;
```

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you correctly your need something like following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMvY7XqCxLNQ172hQ3CrqD/1).

```
select
    code,
    total_amount,
    qty
from
(
    select
        code,
        sum(amount) over (order by id) as total_amount,
        qty,
        row_number() over (partition by code order by id desc) as rnk
    from yourTable
    where code = 1
) val
where rnk =1
```

Output:

```
*-----------------------*
|code total_amount  qty |
*-----------------------*
| 1     80           20 |
*-----------------------*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a subquery, if you want:

```
select distinct top (1) sum(amount) over () as amount, qty
from t
where code = 1
order by id desc;
```